# MYSQL innerjoin insert Multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

Hello i'll give you guys an example of the database tables that are being a pain so i got 3 conected tables yeah trying to make a list into a database anyway i'm having trouble writing a insert query for it

```
vogelsoort

id|naam|idhooftoonder|
```

now idhoofdtoonder references to the id a connection table to sort of translate a list to a mysql database (the logic of the table will be added underneath)

```
hoofdtoonder
|pkey|Id|idondersoorten
```

now idhoofdtoonder references to a the following table its id

```
ondersoort
id|naam
```

I'm sorry for asking this also i'm not experienced enough yet in mysql

edit: the question is since i've tried with a simple insert query it overwrote existing data that i'm looking for help with an insert without overwriting existing id's and connections since (idhootoonder references to hooftonder(id) and hooftoonder idontersoorten references to ondersoort(id) but not all data in ondersoort is connected to the same vogelsoort and i need an insert query that doesn't overide existing connections

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Your question is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 insert-statements, one for each table.
You may use TRANSACTION to do it safely.
You need to use LAST_INSERT_ID() function (your PK fields must been auto_increment for this), docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

```
START TRANSACTION;   

INSERT INTO ondersoort (id, naam) VALUES (NULL, 'data');  
INSERT INTO hoofdtoonder (pkey, Id, idondersoorten) VALUES (NULL, NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO vogelsoort (id, naam, idhooftoonder) VALUES (NULL, 'data', LAST_INSERT_ID());

COMMIT;
```

Comment: yes but the fear is to overide already existing ondersoort table info since from the vogelsoort table have other ondersoorten wich is the biggest issue from overiding already existing data if there is a way to grab the ids from ondersoort on insert and vogelsoort on insert so the table connecting the two hoofdtoonder won't connect or override existing conections

Comment: You may use LAST_INSERT_ID() function. Your PK fields must been auto_increment for this.
Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: thanks buddy your a live safer actually more a project saver but you know what i mean